# CMake set function

Tags: cmake, set

I am trying to learn CMake from [a tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html).  I am not crystal clear about how this `set` function works.

```
set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions)
```

According to CMake document:

> ```
> set(<variable> <value> [[CACHE <type> <docstring> [FORCE]] | PARENT_SCOPE])
> ```

If in this specific case Variable is `EXTRA_LIBS`, Value is `${EXTRA_LIBS}`, then `CACHE` is `MathFunctions`?

Correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, the tutorial you are using is pretty outdated. You might want to use [one of the tutorials from the wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake#Tutorials) instead, or even just use [the new reference manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/index.html) directly.

Comment: Those keyword options you mention (CACHE, etc.) would actually appear in the call, and are optional.  For example, `SET(MY_VAR "Content" PARENT_SCOPE)`.  In your case, none are used, and it's just a straight variable SET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the command is trying to do is *to append the string* `MathFunctions` to whatever value is already stored in the variable `EXTRA_LIBS`.

To break it down:

```
set(VARNAME VALUE)
```

sets the variable `VARNAME` to the string `VALUE`. Note that you can assign multiple values to a single variable, which will effectively assign [a list value](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists) to the variable:

```
set(VARNAME VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3)
```

To access the value of that variable later, you have [to dereference it using `${}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references), as in

```
 message(${VARNAME})
```

If the value assigned is a list, you might want to [access the different elements separately](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/foreach.html) instead:

```
 foreach(element ${VARNAME})
      message(${element})
 endforeach()
```

The command from your question does both the dereferencing of the old value and the assignment of the new value in one line.

A more descriptive way of performing the same assignment is offered by [the `list` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html):

```
list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)
```

---

On a related note: Note that there is a subtle difference between appending to a list and string concatenation:

```
set (EXTRA_LIBS "${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions")
```

Instead of appending, this command will assign a new *singular string value* to the variable, that is equal to the concatenation of the previous values with the string `MathFunctions`.